# Set stack-level tags in cloud formation directly without wrapper template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

**Want to set stack-level tags in cloud formation directly not the resource level tag. I know its doable with wrapper template concept but want directly set the stack-level tags when defining some resources using cloud formation.**

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, but you set stack-level tags using CLI or AWS console when you [deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) your template.

Comment: AWS console only or via jenkins

Answer (score 5):

The stack-level tags are set using CLI, SDK or Console when you deploy your template. It should work regardless of whether you use or not use Jenkins, as jenkis will also have to use CLI or SDK (depening on your setup).

The [stack-level tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html):

> All **stack-level** tags, including automatically created tags, are **propagated** to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports. Currently, tags are not propagated to Amazon EBS volumes that are created from block device mappings.

Hope this helps.

p.s.
You can't set them from inside the template, as they are set when you deploy it.